# Laravel 4, upload_max_filezise directive how increase?

Tags: php, laravel

I use `laravel 4` for development. I creating file uploading but after upload a file with size > 2 mb, i receive next **error:**

> The file "Downloads.zip" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini
>   directive (limit is 2048 kb).

How I can increase limit?

Comment: Increase the limit in `php.ini`

Comment: i use command php -S localhost:4000, where i can find php.ini

Comment: Look in Google, it depends on your operating system and installation method. On Ubuntu is under `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, not sure about other OSs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to increase the value in php.ini. Because you are using the built in webserver you are going to need to specify the php.ini file using the `-c flag` as below:

```
php -S localhost:4000 -c /home/username/php.ini
```

and update the value in that file.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was in wordpress.